# MySql select IN clause string comma delimited

Tags: mysql, select

I need to perform a select query in the following manner:

```
select * from my_table where id NOT IN (comma_delimited_string);
```

What is the correct way to achieve that?

Considering the fact that I am in control of the client code which sends the string, is there a better approach? (the string will hold approximately 30 id's so I am trying to avoid sending 30 parameters, one for each id).

Thank you all

Comment: What's wrong with sending 30 params?  You should be able to write some code to build the query for you to make it easier.

Comment: Is the client code building the string or is it building the query and sending the query?

Comment: @GordonLinoff it's building the string and sending it to a Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use the MySQL [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, comma_delimited_string) = 0
```

---

**Addendum**: Note that the query above is *not* optimizable, so if you have an index on `id` MySQL won't use it. You'll have to decide if the relative simplicity of using `FIND_IN_SET` is worth taking a potential performance hit (I say potential because I don't know if `id` is indexed or if your table is large enough for this to be a concern).

Comment: I don't think `FIND_IN_SET` can use indexes though.

Comment: Definitely not, and good point. I'll update the answer to warn the OP that the query will be non-optimizable. It'll be up to them to decide if that's a problem.

Comment: @EdGibbs id is indexed. The table consists ~3500 records.

Comment: @UdiI at 3,500 records I honestly wouldn't worry too much about optimization, especially with a `NOT IN` query. I'd expect it to run in less than a second. That said, I'd still test it a bit to make sure the speed is acceptable.

Comment: Is there a limit (length) for the `comma_delimited_string`? Is it dictated by `VARCHAR` or `group_concat_max_len`?

Comment: I'm not sure. The question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36062367/2091410) and nobody knew either. I'd suggest experimenting with the max `VARCHAR`. You can put together a string in a text editor with a bit of copy/paste, for example type the line `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`, copy all, paste, copy all, paste, repeat. It'll build to over 65,535 in no time. Then wrap it in single quotes and let it rip :)

Comment: You saved my bro :D .

Comment: @EdGibbs Hi, what if the condition is "IN" instead of NOT IN?
what is the correct FIND_IN_SET Syntax?

Comment: got it, i use != 0

Answer (score 0):

Better answer in the question below as `find_in_set` is very slow as it can't use indexes and tests every value.

[I need a faster way of selecting a value in comma string inside a MYSQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77247650/i-need-a-faster-way-of-selecting-a-value-in-comma-string-inside-a-mysql-function)