# mysql pass value into subquery with in clause

Tags: mysql

Why wouldn't this work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `group` AS G, 
       (SELECT sum(`count`) 
        FROM   `counter` 
        WHERE  `id` IN (G.`ids`)) t 
WHERE  G.id = '1' 
LIMIT  1;
```

I have problem passing group.ids value to a subquery `IN` clause.

The value of group.ids field is:

```
70,194,458,459,570,470
```

Is this possible?

I'm getting this error:

> Unknown column 'G.ids' in 'where clause'

Comment: Does `group.ids` have comma separated numeric values in each row?

Comment: yes the value is 70,194,458,459,570,470

Comment: do you need just `sum(count)` from counter table?

Comment: pronox, I need the `group` fields as well plus `sum(count)` as an extra field.

Comment: no Alma, `group` has both `id` and `ids` fields.

Comment: i think you first need a function in mysql to tokenize your field `G.ids`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a query that will solve your problem, Here basically you are selecting all fields of `group` and just `count` from `counter` and `FIND_IN_SET()` will match `c.id` with any value in your comma separated String.

```
SELECT G.*, (SELECT sum(`count`) 
        FROM   `counter` c
        WHERE  FIND_IN_SET(c.`id`, G.`ids`)) 
    FROM `group` G        
    WHERE  G.id = 1
    LIMIT  1
```

**[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16990392/mysql-select-in-clause-string-comma-delimited) is some extra info about `FIND_IN_SET` that you should know.**

Comment: working perfect, thanks. is `FIND_IN_SET` the solution? I've never used this function. It cannot be done with just `IN` I guess?

Comment: @BeavisIsCool it can be but for that first you'll have to write a function which will take string, tokenize it using comma and return values in each rows so that was kind of long shot, plus linked question says `FIND_IN_SET` is not optimized for indexes so keep that in mind

Comment: @BeavisIsCool BTW your question helped me too in someway, thanks for posting a good question ;) cheers