# how can i do select * from table where column in (variable)?

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, in-clause

```
set @var='a,b,c,d';
select * from table where collumn in (@var);
```

Any another way without put all my query into a string var?

Comment: Are you trying to select only those columns from every record? Or are you trying to select * when those columns arent null?

Comment: find_in_set: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16990392/mysql-select-in-clause-string-comma-delimited

Comment: Works with FIND_IN_SET(collumn,'a,b,c'). tks @AlexK.