# Is there any limit to the comma delimited string in find_in_set in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to know what is the limit of the comma delimited string passed to find_in_set() in a mysql query. I am fetching data from mysql in random order through ajax in chunks of 15 to 20 entries on scroll to bottom and I want that data without any duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql's documentation on [find_in_set()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) do not mention any limit regarding the length or number of elements within a string. The mysql documentation on [limitations and restrictions within mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/limits.html) also do not mention any restriction on the length or number of elements within a string list.

The only limit you will probably have is the maximum length of the data type that holds a string. But with longtext fields, this limit is very high.

However, I would rather store the items in a list in theor own records.

Answer (score 0):

There is no documented limit but the possibility that your query could get very slow. You can insert your data in a temp table and use that.

Comment: but how can it helps me to fetch data in random order without any duplicate entry and one more thing when i got the heavy traffic on the page isn't the server crash down because of multiple temp tables created