# I need a faster way of selecting a value in comma string inside a MYSQL function

Tags: mysql

I need to find a faster solution than my two working solutions below.

If I pass a comma separated string into a function, I need the most efficient way to see if a field matches a value in that string.  For the below example `comma_string` is a text parameter of the function which could equal a string like this `2,56,34,98,23`.

So far my fastest solution is:

```
set _json_set = concat("[", comma_string, "]");
select * from `table` where `ID` in (select * from json_table(_json_set, "$[*]" columns(`c` int path "$")) as `jt`);
```

A far slower solution would be to use as `find_in_set`, however `find_in_set` doesn't use indexes properly, thus it is slower:

```
select * from `table` where find_in_set(`ID`, comma_string);
```

The above examples work fine and of course it would be great to do below, but as far as I am aware, it is not possible because a variable/parameter can't be a set/array, and using the term `in` is fast as it uses indexes properly.  The top solution is only slower than the below concept because of the building of the json table:

```
select * from `table` where `ID` in (comma_string_set);
```

Is there a more efficient way (efficiency being speed) than the top method.  Please remember that this is inside a function.

**EDIT:** Credit to Paul Spiegel, but I slightly altered his answer which was an iteration of my first method, and got a slight speed increase.  The reason it is faster is that as a rule, joins are faster than subqueries, and it got rid of one select, being the subquery. So the challenge is, can anybody make it even faster and improve on below?:

```
select * from `table`
join json_table(_json_set, "$[*]" columns(`c` int path "$"))`jt` on `c`=`table`.`ID`;
```

Comment: I don't think there's anything better than what you've tried.

Comment: Reopened this question because the OP specifically said they don't want to use FIND_IN_SET() which is what the supposed duplicates call for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `JOIN` instead of the `IN`-subquery might be faster:

```
set _json_set = concat("[", comma_string, "]");
select `t`.* 
from json_table(_json_set, "$[*]" columns(`c` int path "$")) as `jt`
join `table` `t` on `t`.`ID` = `jt`.`c`;
```

Note: The query can return duplicates if there are any in the `comma_string`.

Comment: This is an iteration on my first solution but uses a join. As a rule joins are faster than subqueries, however upon testing it with profiling on, it was slightly slower until I altered it to:

select * from table join json_table(_json_set, "$[*]" columns(c int path "$"))jt on c=ID;. Thanks

Comment: I did some testing, and the reason my amendment to your method was faster was that the `jt` table has fewer rows than `table`.
Again thanks for the answer

Comment: So you just switched the tables in the **inner** join and it runs faster? This would be weird even for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can do what you want and make it use an index is to use a dynamic SQL statement.

```
SET @sql = concat('select * from mytable where ID in (', comma_string_set, ')');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;

EXECUTE stmt;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

You are responsible for guaranteeing that the `comma_string_set` is safe and won't cause an SQL injection vulnerability. That is, it must contain only a comma-separated list of id values.

You can't use this method inside a trigger or a stored function, but you can use it inside a stored procedure (unless the procedure is called from a trigger or a stored function).

If you must do this in a stored function, then you need to take a step back and reconsider how you're designing your application.

Comment: I was going to put that in as well, except it is even slower and it can't be used inside a function as you say.  I have a feeling I've come up with the fastest solution.

Comment: Right, you have to decide between optimizing this query and running it inside a function. You can't do both.

Comment: I can do both, the top example is very optimised and both of my examples can be used inside a function.

Comment: If you `EXPLAIN` the first query, you see that it does a table-scan.